# c# datagridview help

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a form showing a gridview.  The data is bound dynamically, depending on several options that the user clicks on.  The populating data works fine (bound from dynamically created datasets).  The problem lies, when I want to switch between displaying data whereby the tables/datasets contain different layouts.  The gridview keeps showing the previous layout.

How would I unbind all data to the gridview, so that I can then display the brand new table?

Thanks.

Comment: DataGridView or GridView, also ASP.NET or WinForms?

Comment: Hi, It's DataGridView on WinForms.  It's bound to a datatable as such:  DataGridView1 = dt;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set datasource = null ?

Comment: I've tried that, but the columns stay there.  I've also tried refreshing and datagridview.columns.clear but that method completely clears the control and doesn't allow any further binding?

Comment: Have you try invalidate() or Reset() ?